# Github project languages (linguist) information not visible?

Tags: github, github-linguist

Normally you can see on top right what your project exists of, how much % PHP, how much % JS etc..

On my current project this is not visible, I have tried removing and adding it again on Github but without luck. It was originally forked from another repo, but that repo doesn't exist anymore now.

[image: Github repo with information about project files]

[image: My current Github repo without information about project files]

Comment: that is odd. if you look at your list of repos it sees Devine-Basic as a php project. github uses the linguist library to automatically determine this information. here's some info on the github blog about that: 
https://github.com/blog/1037-highlighting-repository-languages

Comment: Yes it is weird indeed, I would love to fix it without losing my commits.

Comment: im not really sure what to suggest. i would bring it up to the github support staff :: https://help.github.com/articles/my-repo-is-marked-as-the-wrong-language they have helped me with a few different site-specific problems in the past, they're fast are friendly.

Comment: If I am not mistaken it takes some time until your repo is "parsed". Your repo was created 2 days ago. so don't worry it will show up in a while ;-)

Comment: @JimmyKane When I copy the files and initialise it as new repo and publish it on Github it does show the linguist on that repo (https://github.com/WouterDS/Test--Devine-Basic-copied)

But the problem is that I don't want to lose the current commits on the current repo

Comment: Yes now it works for your repo as well!!!! https://github.com/WouterDS/Devine-Basic

Comment: Wth, it does work indeed now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mailed the Github support (they've fixed it).
They were having caching issues apparently.

Their response:

> Hi Wouter,
>
> Sorry about that. It was a caching issue on our end. I've gone ahead
>   and fixed that, and the languages graph is now showing up.
>
> Let me know if you need anything else.
>
> Cheers, Steve